# awk to remove text and split on two delimiters

Tags: awk

I am trying to use `awk` to remove the text after the last digit and split by the `:`. That is common to both lines and I believe the first portion of the `awk` below will do that. If there is no `_` in the line then `$2` is repeated in `$3` and I believe the split will do that. What I am not sure how to do is if the is an `_` in the line then the number to the left of the `_` is `$2` and the number to the right of the `_` is `$3`. Thank you :).

**input**

```
chr7:140453136A>T 
chr7:140453135_140453136delCAinsTT
```

**desired**

```
chr7    140453136   140453136 
chr7    140453135   140453136
```

**awk**

```
awk '{sub(/[^0-9]+$/, "", $1); {split($0,a,":"); print a[1],a[2]a[2]} 1' input
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { 
    FS="[:_]"               # using field separation for the job
    OFS="\t"
}
{
    sub(/[^0-9]*$/,"",$NF)  # strip non-digits off the end of last field
    if(NF==2)               # if only 2 fields
        $3=$2               # make the $2 from $2
}1' file                    # output
```

Output:

```
chr7    140453136       140453136
chr7    140453135       140453136
```

Tested on GNU awk, mawk, Busybox awk and awk version 20121220.

Comment: No problem, wait even longer, you might get a  bitchin' cool answer.

Comment: Instead if using sub, you can just do `$NF+=0`. The conversion rules for string to number will kick in. The current version will fail on a string 1234gh5hsue

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk -v FPAT='[0-9]+|chr[0-9]*' -v OFS='\t' 'NF==2{$3=$2}{$1=$1}1'
```

This relies on the field pattern `FPAT` that is a regex representing a number or the string `chr` with a number.

The statement `NF==2{$3=$2}` is to duplicate the second field if there is only 2 in the record.

The last statement is to force awk to rebuild the record to have the wanted formatting.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F'[:_]' '{print $1, $2+0, $NF+0}' file
chr7 140453136 140453136
chr7 140453135 140453136
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, more generic solution in terms of NO hard coding of copying fields values to another fields etc, you can simply mention maximum number of field value in `awk` variable and it will check each line(along with removing alphabets from their value) and will copy last value to till end of max value for that line.

```
awk -F'[:_]' -v max="3" '
{
  for(i=2;i<=max;i++){
    if($i==""){
      $i=$(i-1)
    }
    gsub(/[^0-9]+/,"",$i)
  }
}
1
'   Input_file
```

To get output in TAB delimited form append `| column -t` in above code.